# how to make a backspace with TKINTER in python

Tags: python, tkinter, lambda, backspace

this is my first app ,i'm trying to complete my calculator project,and i want to add a backspace button that can remove the last number or text in the entry box
i did some research but i didn't find the exact syntaxthat will work with  my code,i can clear my code but i can't remove only last character

```
from tkinter import *
root = Tk()

root.title("Calculator")
root.iconbitmap(r'C:\Users\iron\Downloads\favicon.ico')
canvas = Canvas(root,height = 378, width =378)
canvas.pack()

frame = Frame(root,bg = "#47FF98")
frame.place(relheight = 1 ,relwidth = 1)
#entry box

var = StringVar()
#to show text in screen
def press(x):
global a
a =  a + str(x)
var.set(a)
# to show result
def result():

global a
total =(eval(a))
var.set(total)


def clear():
global a
a = ""
var.set("")


a = ""

e = Entry(frame,textvariable=var, width=20)
e.pack()

# = button



# equal button
equal = Button(frame,text = "=",activebackground = "#FFD700", bg = "red" , fg = "white",command = result)
equal.pack()
equal.place(relx = 0.8 ,rely = 0.9,relheight = 0.1 ,relwidth = 0.2)

label = Label(frame,relief="solid" ,text = "print anything here")
label.pack()



# plus button
plus = Button(frame,text = "+",activebackground = "#FFD700",bg = "red",fg = "white",command = lambda :press("+"))
plus.pack()
plus.place(relx = 0.8 ,rely = 0.8,relheight = 0.1 ,relwidth = 0.2)

# manipulat
manipulat = Button(frame,text = "x",activebackground = "#FFD700",bg = "red",fg = "white",command = lambda :press("*"))
manipulat.pack()
manipulat.place(relx = 0.8 ,rely = 0.7,relheight = 0.1 ,relwidth = 0.2)
#devide
devide = Button(frame,text = "/",activebackground = "#FFD700",bg = "red",fg = "white",command = lambda :press("/"))
devide.pack()
devide.place(relx = 0.8 ,rely = 0.6,relheight = 0.1 ,relwidth = 0.2)

#subtractions
subtractions = Button(frame,text = "-",activebackground = "#FFD700",bg = "red",fg = "white",command = lambda :press("-"))
subtractions.pack()
subtractions.place(relx = 0.8 ,rely = 0.5,relheight = 0.1 ,relwidth = 0.2)

#point
point= Button(frame,text = ".",activebackground = "#FFD700",bg = "red",fg = "white",command =lambda : press("."))
point.pack()
point.place(relx = 0.6 ,rely = 0.9,relheight = 0.1 ,relwidth = 0.2)
#numbers
zero= Button(frame,text = "0",activebackground = "#FFD700",bg = "red",fg = "white",command =lambda : press(0))
zero.pack()
zero.place(relx = 0.4 ,rely = 0.9,relheight = 0.1 ,relwidth = 0.2)

two= Button(frame,text = "2",activebackground = "#FFD700",bg = "red",fg = "white",command =lambda : press(2))
two.pack()
two.place(relx = 0.4 ,rely = 0.8,relheight = 0.1 ,relwidth = 0.2)

five= Button(frame,text = "5",activebackground = "#FFD700",bg = "red",fg = "white",command =lambda :press(5))
five.pack()
five.place(relx = 0.4 ,rely = 0.7,relheight = 0.1 ,relwidth = 0.2)

eight= Button(frame,text = "8",activebackground = "#FFD700",bg = "red",fg = "white",command =lambda :press(8))
eight.pack()
eight.place(relx = 0.4 ,rely = 0.6,relheight = 0.1 ,relwidth = 0.2)

nine= Button(frame,text = "9",activebackground = "#FFD700",bg = "red",fg = "white",command =lambda :press(9))
nine.pack()
nine.place(relx = 0.6 ,rely = 0.6,relheight = 0.1 ,relwidth = 0.2)

six= Button(frame,text = "6",activebackground = "#FFD700",bg = "red",fg = "white",command =lambda :press(6))
six.pack()
six.place(relx = 0.6 ,rely = 0.7,relheight = 0.1 ,relwidth = 0.2)

three= Button(frame,text = "3",activebackground = "#FFD700",bg = "red",fg = "white",command =lambda :press(3))
three.pack()
three.place(relx = 0.6 ,rely = 0.8,relheight = 0.1 ,relwidth = 0.2)

one= Button(frame,text = "1",activebackground = "#FFD700",bg = "red",fg = "white",command=lambda :press(1))
one.pack()
one.place(relx = 0.2 ,rely = 0.8,relheight = 0.1 ,relwidth = 0.2)

four= Button(frame,text = "4",activebackground = "#FFD700",bg = "red",fg = "white",command=lambda: press(4))
four.pack()
four.place(relx = 0.2 ,rely = 0.7,relheight = 0.1 ,relwidth = 0.2)

seven= Button(frame,text = "7",activebackground = "#FFD700",bg = "red",fg = "white",command =lambda: press(7))
seven.pack()
seven.place(relx = 0.2 ,rely = 0.6,relheight = 0.1 ,relwidth = 0.2)

clear= Button(frame,text="C",activebackground = "#FFD700",bg = "red",fg = "white",command=clear)
clear.pack
clear.place(relx = 0.6 ,rely = 0.5,relheight = 0.1 ,relwidth = 0.2)


root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This ought to work

```
def backspace():
    global a
    a = a[:-1]
    var.set(a)
```

Let me know if this is what you want

Answer (score 1):

Following the syntax of your code so far, you could add a function like this

```
def backspace():
    global a
    a =  a[:-1]
    var.set(a)
```

The `a[:-1]` gets all but the last character of string a

Comment: @younesramou Why did you select the other answer as the best answer? It is just a poor version of my one.

Comment: sorry im new to this ,that why .